# Convert INT to VARCHAR SQL

Tags: sql, select, type-conversion, sybase

I am using Sybase and I am doing a select which returns me a column called "iftype", but its type is int and I need to convert into varchar. When I try to do the select without the convert function I get this error:

> Error code 257, SQL state 37000: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I dont know how to implement the function `CONVERT`. Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: I think you need this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 673, accepted):

Use the convert function.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), field_name) FROM table_name
```

Comment: According to the error, it's `VARCHAR` to `INT` but I'm answering his question, not the error message.

Comment: Thanks. But now I got another error. When I try to do this kind of Select : SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), field_name) FROM table_name. Or even the normal one like: SELECT field_name FROM table_name. Both are correct. I dont know why. But when I try to but a "where" at the end of the select, using the convert or not, I get the same error: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Comment: @Murilo That's because the error is not from what you think. The error tells you that your code is trying to use a `varchar` where an `int` is needed. You need write your actual SQL statement for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry guys. I found the error. In a part of the "where" I was trying to do id = '4' and the id`s type is int and not varchar. Sorry. And thanks for helping me !

Comment: @Tobberoth, for what it's worth, I just landed here by googling.  Part of SO's value is getting answers to almost any question, even basic ones.

Comment: I think it should be `varchar(11)` in case the number is a large negative number.

Comment: this just solved a huge bug on my code, the 200 users using it thank you.

Answer (score 130):

Use the `STR` function:

```
SELECT STR(field_name) FROM table_name
```

---

### **Arguments**

**float_expression**

Is an expression of approximate numeric (float) data type with a decimal point.

**length**

Is the total length. This includes decimal point, sign, digits, and spaces. The default is 10.

**decimal**

Is the number of places to the right of the decimal point. decimal must be less than or equal to 16. If decimal is more than 16 then the result is truncated to sixteen places to the right of the decimal point.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

Comment: `STR()` should be the correct answer, it's simpler and less error-prone than the alternatives.

Comment: For some strange reason, this didn't work for me as it was adding a tab in front of the text, no idea why. Selected solution did work though.

Comment: str pads spaces on the front of the converted number making it useless

Comment: Use LTRIM(STR())

Comment: STR() gives whitespaces on the front of the variable you convert to string. It can be a good choise to convert decimal variables but not for Int.

Comment: LTRIM(STR()) works perfectly with T-SQL. CONVERT(varchar(#), variable) can give unexpected results in T-SQL.

Comment: STR will restrict length to 10 by default. 
SELECT str(1234567890.123) gives 1234567890
Where as ltrim gives much better result
SELECT ltrim(1234567890.123) gives 1234567890.123
If you agree please upvote LTRIM

Comment: MySql seems not working with STR() for me.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `CAST` function:

```
SELECT CAST(your_column_name AS varchar) FROM your_table_name
```

Comment: One can also try the same query "without specifying the length of the characters in varchar". >> *SELECT CAST(your_column_name AS varchar) FROM your_table_name
*

Answer (score 25):

Actually you don't need to use STR Or Convert. Just select 'xxx'+LTRIM(ColumnName) does the job.
Possibly, LTRIM uses Convert or STR under the hood.

LTRIM also removes need for providing length. It seems to be working for integer or float without worry of truncation.

```
SELECT LTRIM(ColumnName) FROM TableName
```

also, LTRIM is better than STR as

```
SELECT STR(1234567890.123)
```

gives 1234567890
whereas

```
SELECT LTRIM(1234567890.123)
```

gives 1234567890.123

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Others are giving me "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: @swifthing, glad it worked. Also, it's the best answer if you want to avoid truncation of decimals.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Cast(Cast([field_name] AS BIGINT) AS NVARCHAR(255))
FROM   table_name
```

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on how to provide quality answers. It's useful to provide context and details on why this might be an ideal solution.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT(DATA_TYPE , Your_Column)` is the syntax for CONVERT method in SQL. From this convert function we can convert the data of the Column which is on the right side of the comma (,) to the data type in the left side of the comma (,) Please see below example.

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), ColumnName) FROM TableName
```