# How to convert Number into String in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have numbers and i want  to convert those number into string in the stored procedure.

Please reply.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert INT to VARCHAR SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979532/convert-int-to-varchar-sql)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=sql+server+convert+number+into+string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without knowing what database you're using, we cannot give an exact syntax. Here's the syntax for MSSQL:

```
CAST(column AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Or

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column)
```

Comment: For me CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column) worked but I needed to use VARCHAR(50) as I am dealing with international telephones with many formats.

Answer (score 1):

A conversion in T-SQL can be done with the CAST function.
A sample can be:

```
SELECT CAST(myNumber AS VARCHAR) FROM myTable
```

where myNumber is your numeric field, and myTable the table in which the field is present. A cast can be used as a parameter for joins too.

Another function you can use is STR:

```
SELECT STR(myField) FROM myTable
```