# Add character end of the value when updating - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to update some column and trying to add  `.jpg` at the end of the value. Values example 4003 and I'm trying to update `ImageFileName` column to `4003.jpg` but `QuestionId` is `INT`. I tried to be `INT` but did not do it. Thanks for help

```
UPDATE Questions 
SET ImageFileName = (QuestionId + '.jpg')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert INT to VARCHAR SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979532/convert-int-to-varchar-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuestionId` is an integer column. You will need to convert to string before append with `.jpg`

```
update Questions
set    ImageFileName = convert(varchar(10), QuestionId) + '.jpg'
```

or simply use `concat()`. It will handle that

```
update Questions
set    ImageFileName = concat(QuestionId, '.jpg')
```

Comment: The issue of `concat` is if `QuestionID` is `NULL` you will end up with `.jpg` string.